# Why the function cannot read?

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
Sub
    strComputer = "asdcom1"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        arrName = Split(objItem.UserName, "\")
    Next

    strUsername = arrName(1) 'strObjUser
    strDomainName = arrName(0) 'strObjDomain
    strCompName = UCase(strComputer)

    Set objLDAPUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & GetUserDN(strUsername,strDomainName))   'Get LDAP details of logged-on user to extract attributes...

    Function GetUserDN(BYVAL UN, BYVAL DN)      '...via this function to quickly get domain details of logged-on user from AD
        Set objTrans = CreateObject("NameTranslate")
        objTrans.init 1, DN
        objTrans.set 3, DN & "\" & UN
        strUserDN = objTrans.Get(1)
        GetUserDN = strUserDN
    End Function
End Sub
```

Comment: is there any error message..?

Comment: Why is the **Function** inside a **Sub**?

Comment: I just found out if the computer is RDP'ed into, it throws error as objItem.UserName is Null. So it works only if there are no remote session on that computer.